# Swift / cut background image

Tags: ios, swift

My background image is set with UIView extension.

```
extension UIView {
    func addBackground() {
        // screen width and height:
        let width = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
        let height = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height

        let imageViewBackground = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height))
        imageViewBackground.image = UIImage(named: "index_clear")

        // you can change the content mode:
        imageViewBackground.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
        self.addSubview(imageViewBackground)
        self.sendSubviewToBack(imageViewBackground)
    }}
```

For segue animation the view moves from left to right. The background image is way larger than the screen, what is visible while the animation.

How can I **cut** the background image to perfectly fit into the view?
`.ScaleAspectFit` does the job, but since it's a picture it looks bad.

Help is very appreciated.

Comment: `.ScaleAspectFill` won't change the aspect ratio, so it won't distort the image but it will crop the parts of the image that don't fit

Comment: no it does not. like I said the view is moving within an animation with secondVC.frame = CGRectOffset(firstVC.frame, -screenWidth + screenWidth, 0.0) and it is visible, that the background image is about 3 times larger than the view

Comment: Did you set `clipsToBounds=true` on the image view?

Comment: I did now and it works perfectly. thank you and feel free to answer so I can accept it. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.ScaleAspectFill` to crop the image rather than scale it to fit.  This won't distort your image, but obviously you won't be able to see the whole thing.

You need to ensure that you set `clipsToBounds=true` on the `UIImageView` so that the cropped area isn't visible

```
extension UIView {
    func addBackground() {
        // screen width and height:
        let width = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
        let height = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height

        let imageViewBackground = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height))
        imageViewBackground.image = UIImage(named: "index_clear")

        // you can change the content mode:
        imageViewBackground.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
        imageViewBackground.clipsToBounds=true
        self.addSubview(imageViewBackground)
        self.sendSubviewToBack(imageViewBackground)
    }
```